# Deeply Nested API printing

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a simple app that will print out images from an API. The API is pretty nested and I already made it into TS to view schema and looked at in Postman (nothing is wrong with the API this is an error on my part.) I know where the error is but I think I need some guidance here.

```
The component is literally just a simple js file that has the image integrated (from the map) so I did not think I needed to show it but I can if needed. Also, I did block out my API key but the error is in the json/API. I know the issue is between setState and mapping.

import React, {useEffect, useState, Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Mars from './Mars.js'




    const App = () => {
    
    const App_Key = "bSfujNx0oXZ7T5czBchcMbfLMg7dYdC9YOR7ZqJZ"
    
    const [mars, setMars] = useState([]);
    
    
    useEffect (() => {
    getMars();
    
    }, []);
    
    const getMars = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&camera=fhaz&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxx
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.photos);
    setMars(data.data);
    
    
    
    
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    
      return(
        <div className="App">
    
    
    
    <h1>Mars Rover</h1>
    {mars.map(mar => (
      <Mars 
     
      image={mars.data.photos.data.img_src}
      
      />
    ))}
          
        
      
       </div>
    
      );
    };
```

Comment: Can you include a sample API response structure

Comment: ya sure it is a small api but: looks like this... {
photos: [
{
id: 102693,
sol: 1000,
camera: {
id: 20,
name: "FHAZ",
rover_id: 5,
full_name: "Front Hazard Avoidance Camera"
},
img_src: "http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/01000/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_486265257EDR_F0481570FHAZ00323M_.JPG",
earth_date: "2015-05-30",
rover: {
id: 5,
name: "Curiosity",
landing_date: "2012-08-06",
launch_date: "2011-11-26",
status: "active"
}
}, it is a bit longer but the comment has a char limit

Answer (score 0):

The response structure shows that the path of `img_sc` is `data.photos[i].img_src`. You are trying to access it using `data.data.data.photos.data.img_src`.

At the place where the state of `mars` is being set, use `data.photos` instead of `data.data`

```
setMars(data.photos);
```

And inside the map function

```
{mars.map(photo=> (
   <Mars image={photo.img_src} />
 ))}
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh yes I knew jt was something like that thanks :)

Comment: Wait, that will only give me item one in array shouldn’t it be [0] since arrays start at zero? Also I wanted to pull img_src from both children not just one

Comment: Since we are using `.map` over `mars`, it will iterate over all the indices inside `data.photos` array and will return a new array of `<Mars/>` components.

Comment: Thank you! can you explain why it was photo in the map not mars? I know it depends on the JSON but i have always seen that term in the map area. just so i can understand where i made a mistake for next time - appreciate your help

Comment: `.map` calls the provided callback function once for each element in the array and every time it will pass that element as argument for the callback function,  and will then construct a new array from the result. So the `photo` variable will represent a single object inside the `data.photos` array. For the first iteration, `photo` will be equal to `data.photos[0]`, for second iteration it will be equal to `data.photos[1]`. And remember, `mars` is same as `data.photos` so when we map over `mars` we are essentially mapping over the `photos` array.

Comment: understand - this data strucuture is difference from what i saw last time but that makes sense. if the array was called "dogs" it would be mars.map(dogs =>

Comment: It does not have to be `dogs` inside the function argument. It can be named whatever you want. It will still point the current index of the array.  `mars.map( abcdabcd  =>` here `abcdabcd` will also point to a single entry inside the `mars` array.

Comment: I suggest having a look at this [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)